# How do I import and export a class from the same Typescript file?

Tags: typescript

I have a file `myfile.ts` which has an import from another module `hello.ts`.

`import { HelloComponent } from 'hello'`

I want to export `HelloComponent` from the same file `myfile.ts`to be imported into other files. I don't want to use `hello.ts` anywhere else other than in `myfile.ts`.

I tried `export HelloComponent` but does not work. The IDE gives me the error `Declaration or statement expected`

How can I import a class from one module and export through the same module which can be consumed by other modules.

Comment: have you tried to import the myfile.ts into other files? instead of importing hello.ts?

Comment: The ```myfile.ts``` gives compilation error ```Declaration or statement expected```

Comment: Did you try: import { HelloComponent } from 'hello'; export {HelloComponent};

Comment: That worked. Please put that in the answer box. I will choose it.